# Password mismatch in dovecot with postafixadmin

Tags: postfix, dovecot, encryption, md5

After many hours trying to set up a new mail server, I just can't figure out why the passwords which postfixadmin store are a mismatch with what dovecot passes for authentication.

In postfixadmin, password encryption setting is:

```
$CONF['encrypt'] = 'md5crypt';
```

And in dovecot

```
default_pass_scheme = MD5-CRYPT
```

I've tried to log in using

```
telnet
doveadm
desktop mail client
```

And in all three cases the mail.log always shows the same result

```
Jun  4 19:02:14 mail dovecot: auth-worker(8215): sql(user@domain.com): Password mismatch
Jun  4 19:02:14 mail dovecot: auth-worker(8215): Debug: sql(user@domain.com): MD5-CRYPT(oSPYmCa5Lhzc2ok2bLfQNqDCx) != '$1$37cc98c3$FeIfz2v7CfeSroJkyH4rK0'
Jun  4 19:02:16 mail dovecot: auth: Debug: client passdb out: FAIL#0111#011user=user@domain.com
```

To me it looks like dovecot encrypts password with MD5-CRYPT() in a way that doesn't match the database entry made by postfixadmin.
Is this the problem? And if so, how can I solve it?

Comment: Have you resolved this one?

Comment: I'm afraid not. However, after trying with different passwords I was able to login. I think it may have something to do with the characters which are stored in Mysql as a result of encryption. A different password may not have the same conflicting characters. This is pure guess though

Answer (score 0):

$CONF['encrypt'] = 'md5-crypt';

worked for me on Debian11. Hope that can help.

But as the original postfixadmin's encryption was "php-crypt" the admin passord no longer works.

Now I'm looking for mysql function to produce md5-crypt datas.